# Prevent auto increment on duplicated entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have Table called `url_info` and the structure of the table is:

url_info:

```
url_id ( auto_increment, primary key )
url ( unique,varchar(500) )
```

When I insert into table like this:

```
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Tom');
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Jerry');
```

The output is:

```
1 Tom
2 Jerry
```

When I insert like this

```
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Tom');
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Tom');
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Jerry');
```

The output is

```
1 Tom
3 Jerry
```

The auto-increment id is incremented when I try to insert to duplicate entry. I have also tried `Insert Ignore`

How to prevent it from incrementing when I try to insert a duplicate entry?

Comment: you mean to say you dont want to insert duplacate value ?

Comment: @mhasan : Duplicate values are not inserted. I just don't want the id to get increment automatically when i try to insert a duplicate url

Comment: The only solution is to check before insert

Comment: Yep, if it inserts and fails, it'll auto-increment, Eduardo is correct.

Comment: Does checking before will affect the performance ?

Comment: well if there is no insertion of duplictae value then there is no incremnent in auto_increment..check for duplicate values before insert

Comment: Krishna, the check of course will take a little time, but any solution to this problem you have will add a little time to the query anyway

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain some more useful information about what should go in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably worth creating a stored procedure to insert what you want into the table. But, in the stored procedure check what items you have already in the table. If these match what you're trying to insert, then the query should not even attempt the insert.

Ie. The procedure needs to contain something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 url_id FROM url_info WHERE url = 'Tom')
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Tom')
```

So, in your stored procedure, it would look like this (assuming the arguments/variables have been declared)

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 url_id FROM url_info WHERE url = @newUrl)
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES(@newUrl)
```

Comment: No. Insert will not fire any SP but triggers.

Comment: What are you saying? He couldn't make a stored procedure and simply do EXEC *storedproc* Tom   ??

Comment: OK now I understand your approach. Always call an SP with params to insert into table. Check if a values exists. If yes stop processing, else insert. Should work with a lock on SP too.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour in InnoDB. The reason is that they want to let go of the auto_increment lock as fast as possible to improve concurrency. Unfortunately this means they increment the AUTO_INCREMENT value before resolving any constraints, such as UNIQUE.

You can read more about the idea in the manual on [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html), but the manual is also unfortunately [buggy](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63128) and doesn't tell why your simple insert will give non-consecutive values.

If this is a real problem for you and you really need consecutive numbers, consider setting the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` option to `0` in your server, but this is not recommended as it will have severe effects on your database (you cannot do any inserts concurrently).

Answer (score 0):

`Auto_increment` is performed updated by the engine. This is done before hand of checking a value is `unique` or not. And we can't roll back the operation to get back to former value of `auto_increment`.

Hence `NO` to start from where you last read on `auto_increment`.

And it is not an issue in loosing some intermediate values on `auto_increment` field.
The MAX value you can store into a `SIGNED INT` field is `2^31-1` equal to `2,147,483,647`. If you read it *loud*, it sounds *2 billion+*.

And I don't think it is small and won't suite your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE `url_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

When I execute:

```
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Tom');
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Tom');
INSERT INTO url_info(url) VALUES('Jerry');
```

I get:

[image]

Make sure you ID column is UNIQUE too.

As the manual says:

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply
>   to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine. For other engines, a
>   UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain
>   NULL. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index,
>   the column values must be unique within the prefix.

Comment: When you declare to have url as a unique value you are not able to insert duplicates into that field. Is that what you want?

Comment: When i try to insert duplicate url's I just don't want the id to get increment automatically .

Comment: Duik, he wants to stop duplicates. The problem is, because the table itself has the check on it rather than the insert, the insert fails, but as a safeguard the table auto-increments.